# jQueryMobile color swatches,can one have more than 26 swatches?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've only just started looking into jQuery mobile and was going through the Theme Roller.It says '**Create up to 26 theme "swatches" lettered from A-Z**'.What is that I need to do if I need more theme swatches?

Comment: why would you need more than 26 Themes?

Comment: I know what you hav asked is a fair question,but I would like to know if its possible to have more than 26 themes.My colleague who is a graphic designer asked me this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is No. jQM Themes use a alpha [a-z] appendage to identify the theme it will be using and this is limited to a-z.

You could rewrite the methods in jQM to allow for additional themes that exceed or are different then a-z but this is NO SMALL TASK and I would highly recommend NOT DOING IT!

Alternatively you could pull different CSS stylesheets if you exceeded the a-z limitations

- [How do I switch my CSS stylesheet using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846980/how-do-i-switch-my-css-stylesheet-using-jquery)

style sheet 1 would hold 26 different themes and
style sheet 2 would hold another 26 different themes

Comment: good idea. Although I'm already seeing my Android crumbling loading 26+ swatches :-)

Comment: @frequent I would expect to see any mobile device performance to suffer as loading the additional unused themes takes up resources. I just don't see the point of having more than three different themes loaded at one time, but to each their own

Comment: I'm doing a site, where I split the CSS into structure.css and theme.css (ala Themeroller) and then have users upload their own theme.css overriding my default themes=a,c,e with their own. Much better and only three themes needed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, you will need to create your own custom swatch colors if you plan on going beyond the default swatch themes. If that's the case then there are plenty of places where you can get started.

For instance you can look at the "colors" and "patterns" section in this pretty cool looking website (make sure to scroll down to see the content): http://www.mobjectify.com/tutorials/supercharge_your_jquery_mobile_theme/

Also from the same website, you can go ahead and get started making your own custom swatches
http://www.mobjectify.com/theme/

If you like this whole concept and really want to get deeper into the matter of customizing your own JQuery themes then you can start playing around with: http://jquerymobile.com//themeroller/