# Changing CSS stylesheet on button click

Tags: javascript, css

I folks, I've had a good look through but nothing seems similar to mine.

I've just finished creating a custom CMS and now want to implement customization capabilities, like templates.

I believe it uses Javascript but, I have a variety of of stylesheets on a server. css.css, css1.css etc with css.css being the main.

Is it possible that on a button click, I could choose a different sheet meaning that in essence, the sheet I would choose became the main style sheet, css.css?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Using JQuery you should be able to get what you're looking for

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846980/how-do-i-switch-my-css-stylesheet-using-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can insert a `link` element in the head of your page. You can do this using `document.createElement`, or using JQuery if you use that. If you actually want to toggle the style sheets, you can remove the previous `link` element, or just replace its `href` attribute.