# Change CSS of HTML on computer timing

Tags: javascript, css

I have three CSS with me in one HTML, `morning.css, evening.css & night.css`..

My requirement is that, once visitor visits the website, the css should change according to visitor PC timing...

```
Morning.css --> 6.00hrs - 15.00hrs
Evening.css --> 15.00hrs - 19.00 hrs
Night.css --> 19.00hrs - 6.00hrs
```

Can anyone help me with this..??? My requirement is on load not on button click

Comment: Include all styles in the page and change class of `<body>` element with JavaScript based on the current time.

Comment: thnx.. can you help me with Javascript function

Comment: @DhawalMhatre Do some research, try it yourself, and only if you can't, come back with what you tried and we will help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I switch my CSS stylesheet using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846980/how-do-i-switch-my-css-stylesheet-using-jquery)

Comment: @DhawalMhatre To give you a hint, the JavaScript code is pretty simple: `var hours = new Date().getHours(); if (hours >= 6 && hours < 15) { ... }`, etc.

Comment: thnx all for quickly.. its done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function which will set the class to body like the following:

```
function setTimingClass() {
    var hour = new Date().getHours();
    var cls;
    if (hour >= 6 && hour <= 14) {
        cls = 'morning';
    } else if (hour >= 15 && hour <= 18) {
        cls = 'evening';
    } else {
        cls = 'night';
    }

    document.body.className = document.body.className + ' ' + cls;

}
```

And call the function on body's onload. And then use this classes in your css file to style accordingly

Comment: well this only changes the body's class.  You probably can do something similar and change the REL of a LINK tag to switch style sheets, but I don't remember if that changes the styles dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example function like this:

```
function applyClass(){
   var date = new Date();
   var hour = date.getHours();
   if(hour >= 6 && hour < 15) {
      // apply 'morning' class to body
   } else if(hour >= 15 && hour < 19) {
      // apply 'evening' class to body
   } else {
      // apply 'night' class to body
   }
}
```

How to append class to DOM element you can easily find on another thread of stackoverflow

Comment: What will happen if now `hour` is `6` or `15`? Night?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JS or any other programming language like php to achieve this.

For me easiest way will be loading all 3 scripts and adding class to body depands on hour.

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();
    if(h >= 6 && <= 15) {
        document.body.setAttribute('class','morning');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `document.body` is shorter, innit? Whereas `className` property was developed specifically to amend element's class.

Answer (score 0):

With this function you can check time and class to the dom element

```
(function(){
    var currentdate = new Date(); 
    var datetime = currentdate.getHours();
    if(datetime >=6 && datetime<15){
     // moning class
    }
        else if(datetime >=15 && datetime<19){
     // evening classes
    }
    else{
     // night class
    }
    alert(datetime)
    }());
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/08azhbxu/4/)