# Switching stylesheets using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to find the right code in jquery that will allow me to switch between stylesheets fast with buttons. I currently have no jquery, for all of mine failed. I am still learning it. Anyway, here is the html:

```css
/* Theme 1 */
body {
 background: #ff4455;
}
/* Theme 2 */
body {
 background: #ee7744;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <input type="button" id="theme1">
 <input type="button" id="theme2">

 <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Here is a snippet of the code. I need the jquery inside the `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

Thanks for your help! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `style` elements with `type` set to `text/plain` ; on click of `input type="button"` set `style type="text/css"` to text content of `style type="text/plain"` having `class` same as `id` of `input type="button"` clicked . Approach maintains all `css` in same document , without need to request external style sheet at each toggle of styles

```js
$("input[type=button]").click(function() {
  $("[type$=css]").text($("." + this.id).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<style type="text/plain" class="theme1">
  /* Theme 1 */ 
  body { background: #ff4455; }
</style>
<style type="text/plain" class="theme2">
  /* Theme 2 */ 
  body { background: #ee7744; }
</style>

<body>
  <input type="button" id="theme1" value="theme1">
  <input type="button" id="theme2" value="theme2">
</body>
```

Comment: Also works great, thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

You have the same problem with this one, why don't take sometime to look into this.

They used jquery to change the attribute value of the link to the stylesheet.

[How do I switch my CSS stylesheet using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846980/how-do-i-switch-my-css-stylesheet-using-jquery)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There should be many similar questions and answers, here's one anyway.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/sheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="sheet1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="theme1">
    <input type="button" id="theme2">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#theme1').click(function(){
            $('#sheet2').remove();
            $('head').append('<link href="css/sheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" id="sheet1" />');
        });
        $('#theme2').click(function(){
            $('#sheet1').remove();
            $('head').append('<link href="css/sheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" id="sheet2" />');
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `<head>` section, put something like this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="currentStyle" href="theme1.css">
```

Then in your code block, do something like this:

```
 $( function()
 {
      $("button").click( function()
           {
                $("#currentStyle").attr( "href", $(this).attr("id") + ".css" );
           } );
 } );
```

It will hook up a function that is called whenever a button is clicked to set the page's style sheet to be the button's ID value with ".css" appended to it.  So "theme1.css" if the button with id="theme1" is clicked.