# Toggle between two stylesheets

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add in a very simple method of switching between 2 stylesheets.

I can get the stylesheet to fire on click but not able to toggle it back to its original:

```
<button id="css_toggle" title="I'm a tooltip!">Text</button>
<div class="sq"></div>
```

```js
$('#css_toggle').click(function () {
  $('link[href="http://localhost:8888/rip-access/wp-content/themes/RIP/assets/css/style.css"]').attr('href', 'http://localhost:8888/rip-access/wp-content/themes/RIP/assets/css/style1.css').toggle();
});
```

this is a VERY simple example so I can understand how to do it before I continue on. Any ideas how I can get it toggle back to the first stylesheet?

Comment: You cant get it back to the original because your jQuery selector cant find any elements ( `$('link[href="http://localhost:8888/rip-access/wp-content/themes/RIP/assets/css/style.css"]')`. Try using ID and just change the `href` on click.

Comment: @VTodorov could you show a simple example?

Comment: A better, and more reliable, solution would be to use a single stylesheet and toggle the classes by making them depend on a class on the `body`. You can then just toggle that class when needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an alternative solution to consider if, for some reason, Rory's solution cannot be applied. It's ideal to simply toggle a `body` class and use this class as a *base selector* - I've recently applied this method for an application switching between a dark and light theme, then storing it to `localStorage` so that the changes are "remembered" e.g:

```
<style>
    .nocturnal-theme p {
       background: black;
       color: white;
    }

    .diurnal-theme p {
       background: white;
       color: black;
    }
</style>

<script>
/* Toggle Theme */
jQuery('.toggle-theme').on('click', function(){
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass('toggle-diurnal')) {
        jQuery('body').removeClass('diurnal-theme').addClass('nocturnal-theme');
        localStorage.setItem('theme','nocturnal-theme');
    } else if(jQuery(this).hasClass('toggle-nocturnal')) {
        jQuery('body').removeClass('nocturnal-theme').addClass('diurnal-theme');
        localStorage.setItem('theme','diurnal-theme');
    }
    var themeSet = localStorage.getItem('theme');
});
</script>
```

**Summary**

1. The below solution stores the *relative* filepaths (typical of
   standard Wordpress installations) to variables (you may not always have unique identifiers (`id` attribute values) available to use, and since editing core files, to include one, is not considered good practice (for reasons that won't be touched on here) it may be better to store these filepaths in variables);
2. On `.click()` of `'#css_toggle'`, the `.each()` method is used to
   loop through all instances of stylesheets (of which there would most
   likely be a few), it also allows us to redefine the scope of
   `$(this)` which will prove helpful moving forward;
3. Through each iteration of the loop, the `link` currently in scope
   has its `href` attribute stored in a variable;
4. The stored value of this attribute is then compared with the
   *relative filepaths* we stored in variables previously
5. If they are found to contain these stored values, the `href`
   attribute of the `link` element in question is updated accordingly

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
var defaultSS = '/wp-content/themes/RIP/assets/css/style.css',
    altSS = '/wp-content/themes/RIP/assets/css/style1.css',
    hrefAttr;

$('#css_toggle').click(function () {

  $('link').each(function(){
    hrefAttr = $(this).attr('href');
    if (hrefAttr.indexOf(defaultSS) >= 0) {
      $(this).attr('href', altSS);
      
      console.log('Was:',hrefAttr);
      console.log('Now:',$(this).attr('href'));
      
    } else if (hrefAttr.indexOf(altSS) >= 0) {
      $(this).attr('href', defaultSS);
      
      console.log('Was:',hrefAttr);
      console.log('Now:',$(this).attr('href'));
      
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8888/rip-access/wp-content/themes/RIP/assets/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">

<button id="css_toggle" title="I'm a tooltip!">Text</button>
```

Answer (score 14):

A better, and more reliable, solution would be to use a single stylesheet and alternate the styling by making the rules depend on a class on the `body`. You can then just toggle that class when needed, something like this:

```js
$('#css_toggle').click(function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('default highlight');
});
```

```css
body.default .sq {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}   

body.highlight .sq {
  background-color: #CC0;
  border: 2px dotted #C00;
}

.sq {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="default">
  <button id="css_toggle" title="I'm a tooltip!">Text</button>
  <div class="sq">
    Foo
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This solution is great, especially if you work with Sass/LESS as you can include your stylesheets with another parent selector

Comment: But somehow this method can make kinda some problem, like big `css` size for some case. could not tell it's great, but good solution.

Comment: Depends  where OP *or in future someone else* want to use this, using small styles or big. for example someone decide to re-design whole template. But right.. maybe it's no matter.

Comment: +1. I've done this in the past and it worked great. I don't remember all the details, but IIRC we separated option 1 and option 2 into two separate SCSS files, which were then transpiled and merged together.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of long `href` use `link[href*="style.css"]` to find `style.css`

```js
var click = false;
var path = '/rip-access/wp-content/themes/RIP/assets/css/';

$('#css_toggle').on('click', function() {
  if (!click) {
    $('link[href*="style.css"]').attr('href', path + 'style1.css');
    click = true;
    console.log('changed to style1.css');
  } else {
    $('link[href*="style1.css"]').attr('href', path + 'style.css');
    click = false;
    console.log('changed to style.css');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="css_toggle" title="I'm a tooltip!">Toggle</button>
<link href="/rip-access/wp-content/themes/RIP/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

*And also you could use an `ID` instead of selecting by file name.*

```
$('#css') // jquery selector

<link id="css" href="..." rel="stylesheet" /> // html
```

Comment: The only issue I can see with this is that there may be more than one `link` element with the instance of `style.css` in the string (since it is a wordpress site, multiple stylesheets from various plugins will be served).

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Agree, and i recommended to use an `ID` instead.

Answer (score 3):

There is the requested simple example:

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id='styles' href='path_to_your_style_1'>
<button id="css_toggle" title="I'm a tooltip!">Text</button>
```

JS:

```
 $('#css_toggle').click(function () {
  if ($("link[id='styles']").attr('href') == 'path_to_your_style_1'){
    $("link[id='styles']").attr('href', 'path_to_your_style_2');
  } else { 
    $("link[id='styles']").attr('href', 'path_to_your_style_1');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **detach** using jquery

```js
<script>
    (function() {
      var styles = {
        light: $("#light").detach(),
        dark:  $("#dark")
      };

      $("input[name=chooseStyle]").click(function() {
        var other = this.value === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
        styles[this.value].appendTo('head');
        styles[other].detach();
      });
    })();
  </script>
```

[Demo link](http://jsbin.com/aduYodEz/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this :

```js
let test = true;
$('#css_toggle').click(function() {
  if(test) {
    $('link.sty').attr("href","style.css");
    test = false;
  } else {
    $('link.sty').attr("href","style1.css");
    test = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link class="sty" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<button id="css_toggle" title="I'm a tooltip!">Text</button>
<div class="sq"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as some previous answers, but hopefully easy to follow for relative beginners like me:

In summary, this code produces a button that switches between two stylesheets (light.css and dark.css), and also updates the text on the button.

(1) *In your HTML*, give the stylesheet link an id (`style`), and set up an empty div (`button-container`), which will contain the button:

```
<head>
<link id="style" rel="stylesheet" href="light.css" />
</head>

<body> 
<div class="button-container"></div>
</body>
```

(2) In your *script block or script.js file*, store the current href value of the stylesheet link in a variable (`theme`):

```
let theme = $("head link#style").attr("href");
```

(3) Insert a button into your button-container div. The button has an onclick handler, which calls a function called `toggleTheme`:

```
$(".button-container").html('<button id="theme" onclick="toggleTheme()">dark mode</button>');
```

(4) the toggleTheme function checks the current value of the variable theme, assigns it the value of the other stylesheet, and updates the button text:

```
function toggleTheme() {
    if (theme == "light.css") {
        theme = "dark.css";
        $("head link#style").attr("href", theme);
        $(".theme").html(
            '<button id="theme" onclick="toggleTheme()">light mode</button>'
        );
    } else {
        theme = "light.css";
        $("head link#style").attr("href", theme);
        $(".theme").html(
            ' <button id="theme" onclick="toggleTheme()">dark mode</button>'
        );
    }
}
```