# Toggling between 2 CSS sheets

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I wish to toggle between 2 CSS sheets. I nearly have code working - but it only switches once, and I am not sure the best way to implement a toggle so I can go back and forth and back and forth.

I want to switch between "normal.css" and "highContrast.css" with one button, and update the text of the button on each change.

In my HTML I have :

```
  <div class="high">
                <button class="normal" id="myButton" value="Hover" onclick="changeClass('css/highContrast.css', 0)" ">High Contrast Mode</button>
              </div>
```

In my JS I have :

```
<script>
    function changeClass(cssFile, cssLinkIndex) {

      var oldlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(cssLinkIndex);

      var newlink = document.createElement("link");
      newlink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
      newlink.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
      newlink.setAttribute("href", cssFile);
      document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).replaceChild(newlink, oldlink);

  document.getElementsByClassName("normal").setAttribute("text", "Normal mode");
  var div = document.getElementById ("myButton");
  div.onclick= "changeClass('css/style.css', 0)";

      }
</script>
```

What is the best way for me to, instead of just passing in highContrast.css as a param, toggle between the 2 CSS files? I was thinking of doing it with a for loop and % 2....but I am sure there is a cleaner way.

Also, the last piece, to update the text, doesn't work either. I assume I am targetting the text incorrectly, and I could fix it to update correctly with a switch statement, but I am not sure how to write it.

Comment: maybe an if/else statement?

Comment: It's better and more reliable to use a single stylesheet and just toggle the classes. For example give the body a class `highcontrastmode` and add stylesheets as follows: `body.highcontrastmode nav { ... }`. Then simply add/remove the class from the `body` node with JavaScript.

Comment: Tangentialy related: look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Alternative_style_sheets https://alistapart.com/article/alternate/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle between two stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772015/toggle-between-two-stylesheets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could decide which css file to choose based on the text that is currently shown on your myButton button. If it's 'High Contrast Mode' use the other and vice versa.

Something like:

```
function changeClass() {
  var text = document.getElementById("myButton").firstChild.data;
  switch (text) {
    case "High Contrast Mode":
      // apply normal mode css

      // switch text on button
      document.getElementById("myButton").firstChild.data = "Normal Mode";
      break;
    case "Normal Mode":
      // apply high contrast mode css

      // switch text on button
      document.getElementById("myButton").firstChild.data = "High Contrast Mode";
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more reliable way than switching between two stylesheets would be to have all the styles in 1 stylesheet.

```js
document.getElementById("toggleContrastMode").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.body.classList.toggle("highcontrastmode"); // Add or remove the class.
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
}

body.highcontrastmode {
    background-color: black;
}

.highcontrastmode nav {
    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<button id='toggleContrastMode'>Toggle contrast</button>
```