# Load & Unload Stylesheet on Key Press

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for a way to turn on and off a stylesheet on my page. I have a stylesheet that calls all of my colors on the page. I'd like to be able to enable or disable this stylesheet by pressing a keyboard key. Lil help?

Comment: Check answers on the duplicate , try to change the event from click to keypress, later if you have your own code and puntual question post it.

Comment: Where's the duplicate? Not sure how it got posted twice. I'm sure it's something I did. It wasn't intentional.

Comment: Hi, duplicate doesn't mean you post it twice. Means a similar question was already answered, if you go to that question you can find the answer you need.... http://stackoverflow.com/a/7847009/2887133 just change the click to keypress event. ;)